# How to compare records from PySpark data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to compare 2 data frames and I want to pull out the records based on below 3 conditions.

1. If the record is matching, 'SAME' should come in a new column FLAG.
2. If the record not matching, if it is from df1 (suppose No.66), 'DF1'  should come in FLAG column.
3. If the record not matching, if it is from df2 (suppose No.77), 'DF2' should come in FLAG column.
   Here whole RECORD need to consider and verify. Record wise comparison.
   Also i need to check like this for millions of records using PySpark code.

**df1:**

```
No,Name,Sal,Address,Dept,Join_Date
11,Sam,1000,ind,IT,2/11/2019
22,Tom,2000,usa,HR,2/11/2019
33,Kom,3500,uk,IT,2/11/2019
44,Nom,4000,can,HR,2/11/2019
55,Vom,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019
66,XYZ,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019
```

**df2:**

```
No,Name,Sal,Address,Dept,Join_Date
11,Sam,1000,ind,IT,2/11/2019
22,Tom,2000,usa,HR,2/11/2019
33,Kom,3000,uk,IT,2/11/2019
44,Nom,4000,can,HR,2/11/2019
55,Xom,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019
77,XYZ,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019
```

**Expected Output:**

```
No,Name,Sal,Address,Dept,Join_Date,FLAG
11,Sam,1000,ind,IT,2/11/2019,SAME
22,Tom,2000,usa,HR,2/11/2019,SAME
33,Kom,3500,uk,IT,2/11/2019,DF1
33,Kom,3000,uk,IT,2/11/2019,DF2
44,Nom,4000,can,HR,2/11/2019,SAME
55,Vom,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019,DF1
55,Xom,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019,DF2
66,XYZ,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019,DF1
77,XYZ,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019,DF2
```

I loaded input data like below, but not getting idea on how to proceed.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("D:\\inputs\\file1.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("D:\\inputs\\file2.csv")
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# Requisite packages to import
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, count, col, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Create the two dataframes
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',1000,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                 (33,'Kom',3500,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                 (55,'Vom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),(66,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')],
                                 ['No','Name','Sal','Address','Dept','Join_Date']) 
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',1000,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                  (33,'Kom',3000,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                  (55,'Xom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),(77,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')],
                                  ['No','Name','Sal','Address','Dept','Join_Date']) 
df1 = df1.withColumn('FLAG',lit('DF1'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('FLAG',lit('DF2'))

# Concatenate the two DataFrames, to create one big dataframe.
df = df1.union(df2)
```

Use [window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) function to check if the count of same rows is more than 1 and if it indeed is, then mark column `FLAG` as `SAME`, else keep it the way it is. Finally, drop the duplicates.

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy('No','Name','Sal','Address','Dept','Join_Date').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
df = df.withColumn('FLAG', when((count('*').over(my_window) > 1),'SAME').otherwise(col('FLAG'))).dropDuplicates()
df.show()
+---+----+----+-------+----+---------+----+
| No|Name| Sal|Address|Dept|Join_Date|FLAG|
+---+----+----+-------+----+---------+----+
| 33| Kom|3000|     uk|  IT|2/11/2019| DF2|
| 44| Nom|4000|    can|  HR|2/11/2019|SAME|
| 22| Tom|2000|    usa|  HR|2/11/2019|SAME|
| 77| XYZ|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF2|
| 55| Xom|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF2|
| 11| Sam|1000|    ind|  IT|2/11/2019|SAME|
| 66| XYZ|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF1|
| 55| Vom|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF1|
| 33| Kom|3500|     uk|  IT|2/11/2019| DF1|
+---+----+----+-------+----+---------+----+
```

Comment: Right now, this solution works excellent for me. Earlier i did not understand window functions. This is excellent even for millions of records also. The other solution also fine, but while working with huge data, found few issues.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @cph_sto, what would you recommend for 50+ columns? Instead of typing up the name of the columns?

Comment: what would you recommend for 50+ columns? Instead of typing up the name of the columns? @RK

Comment: What is sys.maxsize?

Comment: Maximum number possible in python

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem with the creation of temporary columns to indicate the source and a `join`. Then you only have to check for the conditions, i.e. if both sources are present or if only one source is there and which one.

Consider the following code:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',1000,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),\
(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),(33,'Kom',3500,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),\
(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),(55,'Vom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),\
(66,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')], \
["No","Name","Sal","Address","Dept","Join_Date"])

df2= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',1000,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),\
(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),(33,'Kom',3000,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),\
(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),(55,'Xom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),\
(77,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')], \
["No","Name","Sal","Address","Dept","Join_Date"])
#creation of your example dataframes

df1 = df1.withColumn("Source1", lit("DF1"))
df2 = df2.withColumn("Source2", lit("DF2"))
#temporary columns to refer the origin later

df1.join(df2, ["No","Name","Sal","Address","Dept","Join_Date"],"full")\
#full join on all columns, but source is only set if record appears in original dataframe\
.withColumn("FLAG",when(col("Source1").isNotNull() & col("Source2").isNotNull(), "SAME")\
#condition if record appears in both dataframes\
.otherwise(when(col("Source1").isNotNull(), "DF1").otherwise("DF2")))\
#condition if record appears in one dataframe\
.drop("Source1","Source2").show() #remove temporary columns and show result
```

Output:

```python
+---+----+----+-------+----+---------+----+
| No|Name| Sal|Address|Dept|Join_Date|FLAG|
+---+----+----+-------+----+---------+----+
| 33| Kom|3000|     uk|  IT|2/11/2019| DF2|
| 44| Nom|4000|    can|  HR|2/11/2019|SAME|
| 22| Tom|2000|    usa|  HR|2/11/2019|SAME|
| 77| XYZ|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF2|
| 55| Xom|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF2|
| 11| Sam|1000|    ind|  IT|2/11/2019|SAME|
| 66| XYZ|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF1|
| 55| Vom|5000|    mex|  IT|2/11/2019| DF1|
| 33| Kom|3500|     uk|  IT|2/11/2019| DF1|
+---+----+----+-------+----+---------+----+
```

Comment: did you include the import? `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`  then usually you should be able to call isNotNull() on a column

Comment: You can also replace the condition with `.withColumn("FLAG",when((col("Source1")=="DF1") & (col("Source2") == "DF2"), "SAME").otherwise(when(col("Source1") == "DF1", "DF1").otherwise("DF2")))`, which does not check for null now but for the origin

Comment: the sqlContext is probably not needed for you, since you create the dataframes when you read the files. I only used this to create your examples as a dataframe.

Comment: sorry to kill your time : this time getting : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'equalTo'.  Using below statement now:

df1.join(df2, ["No","Name","Sal","Address","Dept","Join_Date"],"full").withColumn("FLAG",when((col("Source1")=="DF1") & (col("Source2") == "DF2"), "SAME").otherwise(when(col("Source1").isNotNull(), "DF1").otherwise("DF2"))).drop("Source1","Source2").show()

Comment: Strange if I just copy this code, I can execute it and get the desired result. My guess is that somehow the `col` function does not work properly, because it should return the specific column and not a string. If the import is correct, which could be something similar to `from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, when` then it seems to depend on your runtime environment. You could try to reference the column as `df1.Source1`, etc. but then you have to assign the join result to a variable

Comment: Now it is working fine my side, its some setup issue... Thanks a lot.